# Reproducing cutoff in xgboost.train() with XGBClassifier()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I've gotten xgboost to generate good predictions by using xgboost.train().

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=.6)
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train)

param = {'max_depth':7, 'silent':1}
bst = xgb.train(param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=2)
y_pred = bst.predict(xgtest)
y_pred = [1. if y_cont > .28  else 0. for y_cont in y_pred]
y_true = y_test
```

This approach wasn't producing good results (I am trying to maximize the f1 score) until I realized that the f1 score increases significantly when setting a threshold on the outputs. This threshold turned out to be .28. Here are some of the predictions before I set the cutoff and convert to 0s and 1s:

```
[ 0.25447303  0.25383738  0.24621713 ...,  0.24621713  0.24621713 0.24621713]
```

But now I want to tune my parameters (using GridSearchCV()), which means that I'll need to reproduce what I did in xgboost.train() above with XGBClassifier().

I realize that things might get tricky because the (default) objective function in xgboost.train() is none, and for XGBClassifier() it's 'binary:logistic'. XGBClassifier() returns the class and not the probability, which is useful in most cases but not here. I've tried predict_proba() with XGBClassifier() and then setting a cutoff, but it seemed pretty useless since the probabilities I were getting were super close to 0 and 1:

```
[[  9.99445975e-01   5.54045662e-04]
 [  9.89062011e-01   1.09380139e-02]
 [  9.95234787e-01   4.76523908e-03]
```

How can I finish the code below do the equivalent of xgboost.train() but with XGBClassifier? When I've tried XGBClassifier without a cutoff, I would get a horrible f1 score.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=.6)
rf = XGBClassifier(max_depth=7, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, silent=True, objective='binary:logistic', nthread=-1, gamma=0, min_child_weight=1, max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, base_score=0.5, seed=0, missing=None)
rf = rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Default objective in xgb.train is "reg:linear". So you have to specify the "binary:logistic" objective explicitly.

Comment: Really? On here it says "objective='binary:logistic" http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

Comment: The objective='binary:logistic' default setting is for XGBClassifier, not xgboost.train. Default objective for the latter is set to "reg:linear" in [learner.cc](https://github.com/khotilov/xgboost/blob/9fb46e2c5efbb7ea7bb0cbb0f815dbdc9b720177/src/learner.cc#L205) when neither "objective" nor "num_class" parameter was provided.

Comment: Okay, so what would this look like in my implementation (the bottom few lines of code in my post), also taking into account including a threshold like I did when I used train()?

Comment: You need to add 'objective':'binary:logistic' to xgb.train booster param's, and use all the same other booster parameters. Note that num_boost_round is not a booster parameter but it needs to be the same as n_estimators too.

Comment: I'm trying to get XGBClassifier to work; xgb.train works as I want it to. I need to modify XGBClassifier to get it to wokr like xgb.train. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Try this: `XGBClassifier(max_depth=7, learning_rate=0.3, n_estimators=2, objective='reg:linear')`

Comment: I did; that doesn't take into account the cutoff that I'm trying to implement like I did with train()

Comment: You will apply cutoff to the second column of the results of `predict_proba()`